# how I create rightClickHandler in smartGWT?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I want to use **rightClickHandler** in ***smartGWT Calender*** widget. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Menu mainMenu = new Menu();

//menu items

 widget.setContextMenu(mainMenu);
```

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/ContextMenuSampleSmartGWT.htm

[How to handle right mouse click on the specific Event in SmartGWT Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597172/how-to-handle-right-mouse-click-on-the-specific-event-in-smartgwt-calendar#)

Comment: How this will help in Calendar widget ???

Comment: calendar is not an Widget ??

Answer (score 0):

You can try for `RightMouseDownHandler()`.

```
Calendar calendar = new Calendar();

calendar .addRightMouseDownHandler(new RightMouseDownHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onRightMouseDown(RightMouseDownEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```